# KDevelop does not see C++ header files

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I have a C++ project built of several shared libraries. Each library source code is placed under its subtree of directories. The main CMakeList file contains a list of `add_subdirectory(<dirname>)` directives. CMakeList files in every subdirectory contain definitions like the following:

```
set (SOURCE_FILES 
     util/src/Connector.cpp
     pub/util/Connector.h
)

add_library(channels SHARED $( SOURCE_FILES))
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(channels  PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

where `channels` is the subdirectory name.

Although the search path for include files is set correctly and compilation works, KDevelop does not see the `Connector.h` header file and, therefore, its parsing and code/class browser do not work.

I know that `.kdev_include_paths` file in every directory might solve the problem. Unfortunately, this approach may not be used due to some additional constraints in our development environment.

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

I use Intel C/C++ compiler on RHEL 7.1 with KDevelop 5.0.4 running from AppImage.

Answer (score 1):

I found and solved a problem which presented similarly - header files not seen and code/class browser failing. The cause turned out to be an error in my code. For the benefit of others who may write a similar bug and arrive at this page, here is what I did wrong:

I had a header only class in a file '**myClass.hpp**' and an empty implementation '**myClass.cpp**'. My **CmakeLists.txt**  cited the implementation, but my implementation did not contain **#include "myClass.hpp"**. The effect in Kdevelop-5.1.0 was that the header file was not parsed as part of the program - hence its includes were not read, and much of the code failed semantic analysis.

Answer (score 1):

On KDevelop 5 this solved my issue:

- Go to menu "Project" -> "Open Configuration..."
- In the window which now opens, go to "Cppcheck" on it's left side and then to "Include Directories" on it's right side
- check the "Use 'system' include dirs" option:

[image: Here is screenshot of that options window]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
include_directories(${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: It does not help

Comment: Does the compiler see the headers?

Comment: Yes, it sees them

Comment: This is very odd. I never experienced such a problem. The following might help you:
Right Clock your Project -> Properties -> Language Support. There are options to add additional headers, parameters and definitions. I hope this solves your problems.

Comment: I've stopped using KDevelop 5 as it was much worse than I expected.

Comment: I can also confirm this is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I experienced the same problem.
Symptoms:
-- Kdevelop 5.1.2 could not find some #includes; they were underlined in source files.
-- There was no problem building the project
Cause:
-- Both symbolic links and the original *.h files were in the paths specified in
   include_directories( ) in CMakeLists.txt. Symbolic link removal fixed the problem.

Kdevelop is probably right to be confused about multiple *.h files with the same name.
Maybe some future Kdevelop release will be able to recognize that it is dealing with only one target.